# using 'postmaster ~/pgdata' to start pgsql server,the 5432 port is being occupied

Tags: macos, postgresql, gdb

I want to learn `postgresql` source code by using `gdb` to debug it.
Before I install `pg` from source code , I already installed it by binary packages(choose the default port 5432).

I install `postgresql` from source code `./configure,make,make install`

Then, I remove the binary package from the application.

and now, when I used the 'postmaster' to start postmaster,It told me that 5432 port is already being occupied(3 tips like"IPV6,IPV4....").

so I change the default port by using `export PGPORT = 5431`,and this time I used the 'postmaster' to start it successfully.

I check `5431(lsof -i:5431)` it display 3 postgres occupy there but when I check `5432(lsof -i:5431)`,it return nothing which seems that it isn't being occupied.

Comment: `./configure; make; make install` Could it be that your compilation has overwritten the existing binary package? Normally you should put it into a separate directory tree, like `./configure --prefix=/my/prefix/dir` Also, take care to use a separate data directory and config/startup files.

Comment: How did you remove the binary packages? did you stop the server before removing them?

Comment: Remove it from the application file.

Comment: I never start it unless it will start when the osx is loaded in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL also create a unix socket (typically in /tmp or /var/run/postgresql or similar). That won't show up with `lsof -i` but will clash of course.

---

The file is typically called something like `.s.PGSQL.5432`

Comment: Is the Unix socket you said  being created by the previous PostgreSQL installed by the binary packages? if it is,I already delete it from this mac.Is it because that it leaves some remaining file(I find one file named "port.socket" in the /var/run)?  thx....

Comment: I find this .s.PGSQL.5432 file in /private/tmp  and delete it. but using "pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/pgsql/data/" still has the warning(Is another postmaster already running on port 5432?).

Comment: You can't just delete the socket if the binaries are still running. Why are you insisting on not stopping the old server properly?